# Joining two tables on a key and then left outer joining a table on a number of criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to join 3 tables together in a single query. The first two have a key so each entry has a matching entry. This joined table will then be joined by a third table that could produce multiple entries for each entry from the first table (the joined ones).

```
select * from
(select a.bidentifier, a.bsession, a.symbol, b.jidentifier, b.JSession 
from trade_monthly a, trade_monthly_second b 
where 
a.bidentifier = b.jidentifier AND  
a.bsession = b.JSession)
left outer join
trade c
on c.symbol = a.symbol
order by a.bidentifier, a.bsession, a.symbol, b.jidentifier, b.JSession, c.symbol
```

There will be more criteria (not just c.symbol = a.symbol) on the left outer join but for now this should be useful. How can I nest the queries this way? I'm gettin gan SQL command not properly ended error.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does Oracle require statements to end with a semicolon?

Answer (score 1):

For what I know every derived table must be given a name; so try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT a.bidentifier, ....
     ...
     a.bsession = b.JSession) t
LEFT JOIN trade c
    ON c.symbol = t.symbol
ORDER BY t.bidentifier, ...
```

Anyway I think you could use a simpler query:

```
SELECT a.bidentifier, a.bsession, a.symbol, b.jidentifier, b.JSession, c.* 
FROM trade_monthly a 
INNER JOIN trade_monthly_second b
    ON a.bidentifier = b.jidentifier 
   AND a.bsession = b.JSession
LEFT JOIN trade c
    ON c.symbol = a.symbol
ORDER BY a.bidentifier, a.bsession, a.symbol, b.jidentifier, b.JSession, c.symbol
```

Comment: @user1216565: take a look at my edited answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: Well every derived  table must be given a name, there are types of subqueries which do not need a name, but if you are using it as a table, it must have a tablename.

Comment: hmm.. I'm getting a SQL command not properly ended error.      SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 933

Comment: I'm running it in SquirreL SQL Client Version 3.3.0 an an oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   `trade_monthly`.`bidentifier` AS `bidentifier`,
   `trade_monthly`.`bsession` AS `bsession`,
   `trade_monthly`.`symbol` AS `symbol`,
   `trade_monthly_second`.`jidentifier` AS `jidentifier`,
   `trade_monthly_second`.`jsession` AS `jsession`
FROM
(
  (
     `trade_monthly`
     JOIN `trade_monthly_second` ON(
        (
           (
              `trade_monthly`.`bidentifier` = `trade_monthly_second`.`jidentifier`
           )
           AND(
              `trade_monthly`.`bsession` = `trade_monthly_second`.`jsession`
           )
        )
     )
  )
  JOIN `trade` ON(
     (
        `trade`.`symbol` = `trade_monthly`.`symbol`
     )
  )
 )
    ORDER BY
   `trade_monthly`.`bidentifier`,
   `trade_monthly`.`bsession`,
   `trade_monthly`.`symbol`,
   `trade_monthly_second`.`jidentifier`,
   `trade_monthly_second`.`jsession`,
   `trade`.`symbol`
```

Comment: hmm.. now i'm just getting a table or view does not exist code

Comment: Check that table names are as you stated

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a **view** of the **two inner joined tables**. Then you can build a query that joins this **view** to the **trade** table using the **left outer join** matching criteria.

In my opinion, views are one of the **most overlooked** solutions to a lot of complex queries.